# Does Sliced Wasserstein Distance assume that the two distributions are zero-mean?

Tags: divergence, wasserstein

Sliced Wasserstein distance (SWD) depends on Radon transform, which is defined as $\mathbb{R}I(t,\theta) = \int \delta(t-\theta^Tx)I(x) \, dx$. The definition of SWD, however, does not use the variable $t$ and it assumes it is zero. This means that the slicing direction always pass through zero: $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}} W_1(\mathbb{R}I_1(\cdot,\theta), \mathbb{R}I_2(\cdot,\theta)) \, d\theta,$$ where $W_1$ is the 1-d Wasserstein loss, and $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ is a unit-sphere with d dimensions. Does that mean the two distributions $I_0$ and $I_1$ are implicitly assumed to have a zero mean?